How do you get Blender Realtime viewport compositor to effect specific objects or materials in scene rather than everything?
I want Suzanne to have the streaks glare, but it also appears on the cube. Is there a way to effect Suzanne only?

It may not be strictly relevant, but a screen-grab showing us what you (don't) want will  literally put folks in the picture, and help to attract answers.

If you want to mask something by object or material pass index or with Cryptomatte like in the regular compositor, this masking is not available in viewport compositing... and I don't know a different way.
